# explode() not working when I use `\n` or " "

Tags: php

I tried several things found on this site such as using PHP_EOL, \n and " " for delimeter on my `explode()` function this is will be used for sending message to multiple users

**HTML code:**

```
     <input type="text" id="myField"   name="tags">
     <input type="submit" name="nm" id="nm" value="Submit" />
```

**PHP script with the `explode()` function:**

```
    $lines = explode("\n",$_POST["tags"]);
      $sql = "INSERT INTO mail(reciever,messages) VALUES(:to, :message)";

for($i = 0; $i < count($lines) -1; $i++)
{
$con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );


$stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bindValue( "to", $lines[$i], PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->bindValue( "message", $enc, PDO::PARAM_STR );

$stmt->execute();

}
```

Am I doing something wrong here? why is `\n` , `" "` ,`PHP_EOL` not working?
I also tried `preg_split` here is my code:

`$lines = preg_split('/\n+/',$_POST['tags']);`

Comment: What is the content in the field? I don't think a `input type="text"` has newlines.

Comment: Why do you prepare the statement inside the loop?

Comment: An `input type="text"` is for one-line input. Do you expect more lines coming from it? Am I missing something?

Comment: Ok guys the reason why I used the `input type="text"` was because I think its the same as what I have seen on the samples like `$string = hello world;` from other website regarding `explode()` function 2nd the reason why I put my prepare statement inside my loop was to loop the whole prepared statement based on the recipient that a user will type... Now why the heck did I still get a downvote despite me being direct and mentioning what I have tried so far, and stating my codes finding similar issues from other users here? Are people here starting to troll other people too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind Guys I managed to make it worked the reason why its not working was because of 
my `for($i = 0; $i < count($lines)-1; $i++)`

I just removed the `-1` and it worked... so the `input type="text"` was not actually the issue here so for reference's sake using text or textarea it does not matter as long as you are using the correct combination for delimiting your string input

here is the php script

```
    $lines = explode("/\r\n|\n|\r/",$_POST["tags"]);
      $sql = "INSERT INTO mail(reciever,messages) VALUES(:to, :message)";

for($i = 0; $i < count($lines) -1; $i++)
{
$con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );


$stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bindValue( "to", $lines[$i], PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->bindValue( "message", $enc, PDO::PARAM_STR );

$stmt->execute();

}
```

and my html page

```
 <input type="text" id="myField" name="tags">
 <input type="submit" name="nm" id="nm" value="Submit" />
```

So my explode() function was actually working its just my for loop that its not working right...

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the

`<input type="text" id="myField" name="tags">`

with

`<textarea id="myField" name="tags"></textarea>`. The `textarea` element supports multi-line user input, the regular `input` field does not.

Also no regular expression split is necessary for such simple task, initializing the `regex` engine is CPU **hungry** exercise.

One more thing - never, ever, ever use `INSERT` SQL statements in a `LOOP`, [read why](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-php).

Comment: still the same nothing was stored in the database

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to split the tags using the "space" character:

```
$tags = explode(" ", $_POST["tags"]);
```

In case, you need the split the text by lines, you'll need the following HTML code:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

and you'll also need the following PHP code:

```
$tags = explode("\r\n", $_POST["tags"]);
```

This will make sure it'll support all browsers and platforms.

Comment: Hi I tried this script and still I get nothing not even a error

Comment: Can you check the values in $tags ?
`<?php print_r($tags); ?>`